# How to apply unittests after coding is done?

Tags: python-2.7, unit-testing

I know this is bad practise (I guess I found out the hard way), but I made a (relatively) long script for a company to generate a PDF document, and plot several images generated via external packages onto it. So this script has a lot of dependancies and at some parts is a little complex.

The company now asked me (well they asked up front, but I never tested anything before in my life) to unit test my code, so they know that (at least the basics) are tested. My problem: I never did ANY testing before, I looked up some reading materials on unit testing, and I think I get the basic understanding of it. The problem I'm facing now is that all of the examples use very small examples (like add a number and test the output).

What is the best way, now that I already have a complex piece of code, to apply the tests afterwards? I've already created a separate test script like so:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')

from PTRGenerator import *
import unittest

class PTRTest(unittest.TestCase):
    """PTR Test case"""

    # preparing the tests
    def setUp(self):
        """ Setting up for the first test """
        print "PTRTest:setUp_:begin"
        # do something
        print "PTRTest:setUp_:end"

    # ending the test
    def tearDown(self):
        """Cleaning up after the test"""
        print "PTRTest:tearDown_:begin"
        # do something
        print "PTRTest:tearDown_:end"

    def testA(self):
        """Test routine A"""
        print "PTRTest:testA"

    def testB(self):
        """Test routine B"""
        print "PTRTest:testB"

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # creating a new testsuite
    newSuite = unittest.TestSuite()

    # adding a testcase
    newSuite.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(PTRTest))
```

A piece of 'complex' code would look like this (I hope it's not that complex at all):

```
# method to show footer.
def footer(canvas, doc):
    canvas.saveState()

    # footer consists of a table with 1 row, to make it look like the headers of the rest of the document
    footerTable = []
    footerTable.append(["PDF V%s" % jf['PDF_version'], "PAGE %i OF 2" %canvas.getPageNumber(), "%s" % time.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")])
    saveString = '%s.%s.%s.%i.pdf' %(jf['external_sample_id'], jf['study_name'], jf['our_sample_id'], args.id)
    footerTable.append(["%s" %saveString, "", "FOR RESEARCH USE ONLY"])

    rowHeight = 15

    ft = Table(footerTable, colWidths=(250, 50, 250), rowHeights=rowHeight)
    ft.setStyle(TableStyle([('FONT',    (0,0),  (-1,-1), HEADERS_FONT),
                ('FONTSIZE',    (0,0),  (-1, -1), HEADERS_FONT_SIZE),

                ## set boxes around appropriate cells
                # hotspot seq coverage box
                ('TEXTCOLOR',   (0, 0), (-1, -1), BOX_TEXT),
                ('BOX',     (0, 0), (-1, -1), 1, BOX_COLOR),
                ('BACKGROUND',  (0, 0), (-1, -1), BOX_COLOR),

                # Align the first line of the footer to the left, middle and right for elements 1 2 and 3
                ('ALIGN',   (0,0),  (0, 0), 'LEFT'),
                ('ALIGN',   (1,0),  (1, 0), 'CENTER'),
                ('ALIGN',   (2,0),  (2, 0), 'RIGHT'),

                # Align the second row
                #('SPAN',   (0,1),  (2, 1)),
                ('ALIGN',   (0,1),  (0, 1), 'LEFT'),
                ('ALIGN',   (2,1),  (2, 1), 'RIGHT'),
                ('VALIGN',  (0,0),  (-1, -1), 'MIDDLE')

                ]))

    ft.wrapOn(canvas, 100, 20)
    ft.drawOn(canvas, 22, 10)

    canvas.restoreState()
```

How do I know what values to check complex output on for example ?

How do I check the output of an image (images are plotted based on variable data) ?

How do I check for element types which are dependant on other libraries (for instance I have a lot of Reportlab objects)

Answer (score 0):

Break your "complex" code up into simpler methods ...uni-taskers. These methods could accepts args upon which then need to operate and return the processed result. Combined, these uni-taskers will preform all the "complex" work.

These simpler methods then become much easier to test. I your test, you can pass in the args and examine the output to ensure the processing was done correctly.

You can also test with sample files. Using know inputs (images, etc.) generate know outputs (a PDF). Now that you already have your functioning code, you can do use test inputs to generate a confirmation PDF. Then run your tests using the test inputs and validate the output of the (like by using an MD5 or SHA1 checksum) against the known valid output.